# Is HDCP working for ATI/AMD cards on windows 8?

Tags: graphics-card, windows-8, hdcp

I have an AMD 6950 and am running windows 8 RTM.

I've tried the Catalyst 12.8 drivers and the 12.9 beta drivers.

With either drive HDCP seems to be non operational.

I've got two dell monitors, one a u2410 and the other a 2408wfp.  Both were previously identified as supporting HDCP in windows 7 with the same hardware.

I've tested the monitors individual on both DVI and display port, and neither one works.

I'm using cyberlinks BD-Advisor to test. My end goal is getting the DirecTv2PC app working again, which is by cyberlink for DirecTV, and requires HDCP.  Currently it shuts off when you start playing a recording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently having Hyper-V installed will cause this issue.

I still cannot get HDCP to work on display port, but after un-installing Hyper-V I do get HDCP over DVI.

Comment: Catalyst 13.1 beta drivers that come with Windows 8(.1) still have this problem. My HD 4850 with DVI only was getting "this cannot be played in hd on this computer" from iTunes despite the whole chain being HDCP-compliant. Cyberlink BD-Advisor reported failure too. Anecdotally, disabling Hyper-V also appears to have fixed resume from sleep (display did not come on).

Answer (score -1):

For now, not much drivers are made for W8. We need to wait until the SDK is out and wait for the companies to update their drivers. I have the same problem with my nVidia Quadro 600.

It's the same thing every time MSFT release a new version: we need to wait for the other compagnies.

That's the good thing with Mac and Linux: NO DRIVERS!

Comment: "Mac and Linux: No drivers"? Both Mac and Linux still have to deal with drivers. Driver support for GPUs on Macs depends very heavily on Apple because they have their fingers in the pie on all driver writing. Driver support for GPUs on Linux is heavily dependent on the OSS community (for the open-source drivers, which usually aren't terribly fantastic due to IP/trade secret concerns with open sourcing) and on the whims of the company, if they want to build a proprietary driver, which usually isn't as high priority as the Windows drivers.

Comment: @sidran32 That's true but Windows doesn't come with a lot of drivers. We need to install them. Mac and Linux both come with universal driver who works great. We need more proprietary drivers only if we really need them!

Comment: That's actually also incorrect. Windows comes with a *lot* of generic drivers. For simpler devices, like printers, these work fine (and are the ones expected to be used by the printer mfgr). For graphics cards, it will typically default to the Generic VGA driver on the disk, but if you connect to the Internet, Windows Update will automatically download a driver specific for your graphics card for you. It may not include all the bells and whistles, but you don't have do much yourself, these days.

Comment: Also, GPU drivers are probably fine for Windows 8. AMD has had Windows 8 drivers out for their graphics cards for a while, now. It might just be drivers for the monitors themselves that are the culprit.

Comment: It's the same hardware I've been using forever, it can't be the monitors.  They worked just fine under win7/vista