# WHQL AMD Readeon HD 5770 Drivers?

Tags: windows, drivers

Are there WHQL Drivers available for the AMD Radeon HD 5770? I've been trying to play video in Windows 8 apps for months, and it doesn't work because I don't have WHQL drivers. I tried searching around, but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try AMD's web site? [Catalyst 12.8](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonaiw_vista64.aspx), the latest version, works fine with Windows 8.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but that's not WHQL signed, so I can't play video in the Netflix app or purchased videos in the Xbox Video app. I've tried 12.9 beta as well.

Comment: Nobody else can either. See [Is HDCP working for ATI/AMD cards on windows 8?](http://superuser.com/q/487038/144961).